# NEF File Error: Could not complete your request because it is not the right kind of document

Tags: nikon, photoshop, raw, error

I took a bunch of photos earlier today on my Nikon D7000 camera in RAW format, as recommended to me by members of this forum.

I loaded all the pictures up onto my computer, but when I try to drag them into Photoshop, I get the error message:

[image: Photoshop Error]

Some Googling brought me to a [page at Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html) which instructed me to Update Photoshop - I did. Nonetheless, I am still getting the same error.

Should I be nervous?? !

Comment: Which camera? CS4 can't run the latest RAW converters and doesn't handle the latest camera models' NEF's

Comment: I don't think you updated Photoshop to CS5 or CS6, which is what you need to do if you want to do this there. As a positive spin to that, CS5/6 have added some very nice features for Photographers. Worth the upgrade in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to be nervous yet.  You may need either an updated version of Adobe Camera Raw or if an up-to-date enough version isn't available for your camera, then you may have to use Nikon's RAW tools (ViewNX) to do the initial adjustments to your photos.  Once you get the photo looking the way you want from the RAW handling software, you can export it as a high quality raster image to be worked on in Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4917), the D7000 compatible raw converter doesn't work on versions of Photoshop earlier than CS5.

Comment: However, you *can* use the [Adobe DNG Converter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=106&platform=Windows) utility to batch-process all of the NEF files to DNG, which CS4 *can* handle.